# Windows Phone 8.1 TextBox

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone

I want to get image from a my windows phone into a textbox or Rich TextBlock . As Rich TextBox does not supported in windows phone 8.1 . So the problem is that Rich TextBlock does not allow to get user input . As I just want to get the user input and also image in a same textbox. 
Thankyou

Comment: You need to be more specific in your question, post some (short) portion of your code.

Comment: I just want to add selected image fro a phone gallery inside textbox in windows phone 8.1 .

Comment: You sound like you're trying to solve the wrong problem - instead, could you design your views so that you can have the image in an imagebox, and the text in textbox(es)

Comment: No, plz try to understand . I have a textbox just like a whatsapp chat textbox . Problem is that windows phone 8 had a feature of Rich TextBox that will do the work of having image as well as getting user's input . But i am doing development in windows phone 8.1 so this feature changes into Rich TextBlock as it does not allow the user to input . I hope the problem should clear now. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    <StackPanel Name="Stack_image" >
    <StackPanel.Background>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="{Binding}"></ImageBrush>
    </StackPanel.Background>
        <TextBox x:Name="email"  />
   </StackPanel>
```

and in behind code:

```
        ImageEncodingProperties imgFormat = ImageEncodingProperties.CreateJpeg();
        // a file to save a photo
        StorageFile file = await          ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync(
                "Photo.jpg", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);

        await takePhotoManager.CapturePhotoToStorageFileAsync(imgFormat, file);

        IRandomAccessStream filestream = await file.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.Read);

        BitmapImage imagetobind = new BitmapImage();
            imagetobind.SetSource(filestream);

            Stack_image.DataContext = imagetobind;
```

Answer (score 1):

you can set your texblock inside a stackpanel and set your image as background. Here's an example

```
       <StackPanel >
        <StackPanel.Background>
            <ImageBrush ImageSource="/Assets/image.png"></ImageBrush>
        </StackPanel.Background>

        <TextBox x:Name="email" 
                         />
    </StackPanel>
```

Comment: but what should be the image source as the user will get the image from image gallery

Comment: you can bind it after user choice, did you already implement the openfilepicker?

Comment: look at my second answer, hope it can help you